# Java Web Container implementation independant development

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jdbc

One of the most important non-functional requirements of any project is the build process in my opinion and that's where I kinda get stuck in my java project, which has just one external dependency, a jdbc compatible database. All the tutorials about spring and deployment out there; I've read them all, but they either say:

1. run it with `gradle bootRun` applications.properties (yes works but on a webserver I'm not going to have any properties-files, but JNDI resource for example) or
2. build a deployable war file with JNDI resources (yes it works on the webserver, but not in my embedded webserver or I'm doing it wrong, but I cannot find any doc about how an embedded tomcat loads a context.xml from outside the jar file).

Now I tried to use the same setup as my server and installed tomcat7 and the @Asyc @Scheduled services run, but no servlets, like a simple /status page should return "OK" just for checking. catalina.out does not show any errors. My /manager from tomcat7-admin says deployment ok, and when I click start: "FAIL - Application at context path /xyz-0.1.0 could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xyz-0.1.0]]"

And now I want to make a cut here and throw every "bootstrap" stuff away and start from zero.

So my question is, am I wrong when I say, that the big deal of my deployment is a jdbc JNDI resource provided from the web container, which is called 'jdbc/xyz' and everyone who wants to deploy my war needs that JNDI. That means so matter if you're using wildfly, jboss, tomcat, glassfish or any embedded server: your server impl has to provide that web container and jndi resource to make it run. And I don't want to configure any tomcat, glassfish or whatever implementation in my war.

Is that wrong?

It would be great, if you could help me. I'm playing around with that many weeks now :( and if A works B does not and vice versa. Would it be easier to use JEE?

Thank you.

Comment: why can't you just use the embedded servlet container and configure the application via application.properties on your server?

Comment: @Cyril Next step is a build server (I already set up) and it deploys to a tomcat server. I don't know how it should redeploy a running embedded instance with the next build? Therefore it should be tomcat on my server and local embedded (self-contained).